# Understanding product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> The context of my question is to solve this problem, but my question is not really about the solution, it's about the definition and implications of the product topology.
>
> Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces and $A \in Op(X \times Y), B \in Op(Y\times Z)$
>
> Show that $A \circ B = \{(x,z) \in X\times Z : \exists y \in Y s.t. (x,y) \in A, (y,z)\in B\}$ is an open set of $X \times Z$

---

**NOTATION**

$Op(\cdot)$ means the open sets of a space (i.e., the elements of the topology of such space).

$\tau_x,\tau_y,\tau_z$ are the topologies of the topological spaces $X,Y,Z$ respectively.

$\pi_x,\pi_y,\pi_z$ are the projections from the product spaces. e.g.  $\pi_x:X\times Y \to X$. I'm using the same symbol $\pi_x$ for the functions  from $X\times Y$ to $X$ and from $X \times Z$ to $X$.

$(\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x$ is the inverse image of the topology $\tau_x$ by the projection $\pi_x$

$Sub(X) = \{A:A \subseteq X\}$

---

The product topology defined in $X \times Y$ is the topology generated by $((\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x )\cup ((\pi_y)^{-1}\tau_y)$, i.e., the smallest topology that contains all the elements in $(\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x$ and in $(\pi_y)^{-1}\tau_y$. *(correct so far?)*

Now, the set $(\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x = \{A \in Sub(X \times Y): \forall (\alpha,\beta)\in A: \exists B \in \tau_x, \alpha \in B\}$ *(is this also correct?)*

If such definitions above are correct, can I make the following claim?

> Let $\tau_{x \times y}$ be the product topology on $X \times Y$. Then $\forall A \in \tau_{x \times y}$ if $(\alpha,\beta) \in A \implies \exists B \in \tau_x s.t. \alpha \in B$ **and/or** $\exists C \in \tau_y s.t. \beta \in C$

Is this correct?(if it is, I believe the theorem I'm supposed to prove is false because I could find sets $A$ and $B$ where only the coordinate with "$y$" would be in a set in $\tau_y$ and the other coordinates wouldn't be in a set of the topologies of $X$ and $Z$ and so the set $A \circ B$ wouldn't be in the product topology of $X \times Z$)

Comment: You need **and** and the final condition that $B \times C \subseteq A$.

Comment: So $$A \in \tau_{X \times Y} \text{ iff } \forall (\alpha,\beta) \in A \exists B \in \tau_X \exists C \in \tau_Y: (\alpha \in B \land \beta \in C \land (B \times C \subseteq A))$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I believe what was confusing me was that my professor stated that the product topology was generated by $(\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x\cup (\pi_y)^{-1}\tau_y$ but instead the correct subbase is $(\pi_x)^{-1}\tau_x\cap (\pi_y)^{-1}\tau_y$. (which agrees with what you said)

Comment: no, the correct subbase is with the union as your teacher said. So the intersection of members from $\pi_x^{-1}[\tau_X]$ and the corresponding set for $Y$ form a base. Which are exactly sets of the form $B\times C$ as stated. @Matheusbarroscastro

Comment: hm... now I get it. Thank you.

Comment: @Matheusbarroscastro: If you have time then you may consider writing an answer to the question to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.